# Manual creation of TFS document libraries

Tags: tfs

In TFS 2010,  if you create a project with an associated Sharepoint site, or even create and link a sharepoint site afterwords you'll see a 'Documents' Node in the project in the Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer, and Visual Studio will give you the ability to right click on that node, create document libraryes and add a document.

If you just create a TFS project with no associated sharepoint site, you won't see the 'Documents' node, but is there a way to create one through Visual Studio without having a Sharepoint site?

Answer (score 2):

No, I believe that function will always use SharePoint.